# Souvenirs from the US and Canada

Tags: usa, canada, food-and-drink, souvenirs, kenya

I will be travelling to the US soon and I would like to bring my family some souvenirs. To narrow choices down:

- Must be comestible
- Must be transportable (over a 23-hour flight)
- Must be distinctively US or Canadian
- Must be available in USA
- Must be allowed duty-free entry to Kenya `*`
- Must be affordable (up to tens of dollars, not thousands)
- Must not require an export licence

Candy is unsuitable, even if a brand not generally available in Kenya, since too similar to locally available products.

A McDonalds meal would be ideal for “distinctively” if it met the other requirements. Even though McDonalds is found almost all over the world it is not established in Kenya, where people only know of KFC. (This is just an example as I will not be carrying a McDonalds meal on a 23h flight.)

`*` According to [IATA TravelCentre](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/KE-Kenya-customs-currency-airport-tax-regulations-details.htm) "fruit, poultry meat and products" are not permitted entry.

Comment: This question is rather broad, as we can only guess what your family would appreciate, and different regions have different signature foods— if you're traveling to Chicago, you wouldn't fill up your gift bag with vidalia onions, or if you'll be in Las Vegas you wouldn't load up on maple syrup, and if they're accustomed to Cadbury chocolate, they won't have any use for Hershey bars. Plus, it may not even be legal to bring vidalia onions or maple syrup into Kenya (I don't know).

Comment: Dried [cranberries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry)?

Answer (score 3):

Maple syrup (or maple candies) is always a winner.
Cheese can also be a good choice (needs to be vacuum sealed).
Smoked salmon (buy frozen and wrapped in cloth in your checked-in bags).
Wild rice is really nice.
...

Comment: Maple syrup is more of a Canadian thing, isn't it?

Comment: OP also asked for Canadian suggestions, but there are Maple syrups producers in New-England states.

Comment: This does seem like something I would go for unfortunately we do have maple syrup though imported. I will consider getting an American brand that  is not available locally.

Answer (score 0):

Beef jerky. This is truly an American thing. You can get different kinds of jerky: beef, antelope, deer, buffalo, elk. Elk might be your best bet, it's one of my favorites, and I think elk only exist in North America.

Comment: is there peanut butter in Kenya ?

Comment: Such meat product imports are banned by most countries including Kenya.

Comment: Dried and cured meat like beef jerky is quite common all over the world and not a very special American thing. In South Africa, a similar product is called 'biltong' and I would be very surprised if there is no such thing to be found in Kenya.

Comment: but can you get elk jerky in Africa?

Comment: @pnuts [this](https://kenya.visahq.com/customs/) reference says Prohibited: • Meat and meat products.